# Form Submission values in Hook Form Alter method

Tags: webforms, forms

I wrote a custom method to do some set of operations when a webform is submitted and that is working fine. However I need to access some fields values that has been submitted in the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform).

The fields in the Webform are: 'phone' , 'emailid'. I need to access these variables in the method `custom_example_some_function`. I tried playing around with some arrays, but that didn't worked out.

```
function custom_example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_22') {
       $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_example_some_function';
  }
}

function custom_example_some_function($form, &$form_state) { 
// Do something
// echo $phoneNumberFromForm;
// echo $emailidFromForm;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find submitted values in `$form_state['values']`, eg

```
$foo = $form_state['values']['bar'];
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `Notice: Undefined index: phone in custom_example_some_function()`

This is the function I wrote.
    function custom_example_some_function(&$form, &$form_state) { 
    $mobilenumbers = $form_state['values']['phone'];
    }

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to inspect `$form_state['values']` and find out what's in it, impossible to guess the exact keys from here

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how can I check the values in it. I tried print_r and render.

Comment: Because of the output buffering `print_r()`/`var_dump()` have mixed results if you call them outside a template file. By far the easiest way to debug Drupal is to install the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) and use the `dpm()` function (`dpm($form_state['values']);`). That will print a Krumo representation of the variable to the messages area, and you can inspect it easily

Comment: Great!! The Devel module really helped.

I used this in the custom function `dpm($form_state['values']);`

Which gave me the exact key.
$mobilenumbers = $form_state['values']['submitted'][3];

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to edit your $form array values.
Now they are passed and locally scoped in *function custom_example_some_function($form, &$form_state)*

Try changing it to `function custom_example_some_function(&$form, &$form_state)` so that you're able to alter your $form array.

Comment: NO! I just to get the fields values in my method `custom_example_some_function`. If someone submitted form with 'phone number' as '1234567', I want this number in my method.